# Mysql SET GLOBAL wait_timeout possible to set it for just 1 database?

Tags: mysql

I have several databases on my MySQL server. On one of them i need to set `wait_timeout` at the maximum. The other databases don't need this. I was wondering if i can just set it for one specific database? Something like:

```
SET database_name wait_timeout = 999999999
```

Also, if i set it as a global value, could this cause trouble for my other databases?

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are, not surprisingly, global.

Would there be any harm in setting it for everything? Possibly if you have code that depends on queries actually timing out, though usually these are bugs.

Can you deal with setting some of these things on a per-connection basis?

Comment: i tried setting the timeout as `SET SESSION wait_timeout` but it doesn't work for me, just wanted to know if i can set it for 1 database

Comment: As far as I know, there are no variables that apply to just one database. It's global or session only.